# generate n random numbers not duplicated using vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to generate n random numbers not duplicated except this numbers ( 81-82-83-84-85-86).

In this VBA code b(1 to 80) I want to do for b(1 to 200) with no repeated numbers ( 81-82-83-84-85-86) and the number_required is the number of rows in one column every time I changed it:

```
Dim b() As Boolean, Bidder_ID As Range, k&, x&
ReDim b(1 To 80)
Dim destination_Bidder_ID As String
Randomize
Number_required = Range("K2").Value
destination_Bidder_ID = Range("L3").Value
Range(destination_Bidder_ID).Select

For Each Bidder_ID In Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(Number_required - 1, 0))
Do
    x = Int(Rnd() * 80) + 1
    If b(x) = False Then
        Bidder_ID.Value = x
        b(x) = True
        Exit Do
    End If
    k = k + 1: If k > 100 Then Exit Sub
Loop

Next
```

How can I generate random numbers from 1 to 200  except this numbers ( 81-82-83-84-85-86 ) that already exist within a defined range?

Comment: That sounds good. What's the actual question?

Comment: How can I generate random numbers from 1 to 200  except this numbers ( 81-82-83-84-85-86 )? i didnt know how to do it ...?

Comment: The first thing you will want to add is a `Randomize` statement right after you start the loop.

Comment: @braX   x = Int(Rnd() * 80) + 1

Comment: Yup - that may return the same value without it. That will be a problem.

Comment: read up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement

Comment: I understand i can use randomize and  x = Int(Rnd() * 200) + 1 but how to exclude this numbers (81-...-86)?

Comment: just make a loop that checks the result number, and if it's one of those numbers, have it try again.

Comment: thanks I'll try @braX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub RndBtwn_Excldng()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, i As Integer

    Set rng = Range([L3]).Resize([K2])

    For Each c In rng
        Select Case Int(rnd * 10) Mod 2
            Case 0: lb = 1: ub = 80
            Case 1: lb = 87: ub = 200
        End Select

        i = Int((ub - lb + 1) * rnd + lb)
        Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, i) >= 1
            i = Int((ub - lb + 1) * rnd + lb)
        Loop

        c = i
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: if I want to to run this code for each same id, I mean if id_number = id_number+1 generate random numbers not duplicated for them.. I put this condition but it hangs up `If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i+1,1) Then` can you help me for that? @AsUsual